# Relationship of eigenvalue/eigenvector of hermitian matrix R and QRQ (Q is diagonal)

Tags: matrices

For a hermitian matrix R and a diagonal one Q, is there any relationship between eigenvalues/eigenvectors of R and QRQ?

To be specific, assuming the eigenvalue decomposition of R is R=VDV*, then can the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of QRQ be represented by V, D & Q?

Thanks a lot!

Some guys have given some [hints](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158608/relationship-of-eigenvalue-eigenvector-of-hermitian-matrix-r-and-qrq-q-is-diago) for this question on mathoverflow, which I think are helpful. Thank you all for your attention!

Comment: i have tried to answer uisng matlab software if i am wrong i will delete it

Comment: but actually for  this case  i think,that i would be  $R*Q^2$,

Answer (score 0):

let take following example

```
A=[2 2+i 4;2-i 3 i;4 -i 1]

A =

   2.0000 + 0.0000i   2.0000 + 1.0000i   4.0000 + 0.0000i
   2.0000 - 1.0000i   3.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i
   4.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 1.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
```

it's transpose  let us check

```
A'

ans =

   2.0000 + 0.0000i   2.0000 + 1.0000i   4.0000 + 0.0000i
   2.0000 - 1.0000i   3.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i
   4.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 1.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
```

now  let us take some diagonal element

```
 X=[2 1 3];

>> y=diag(X)

y =

     2     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     3
```

now about eigenvalue of  A

```
[U D]=eig(A)

U =

   0.6558 - 0.0511i  -0.1537 + 0.1936i  -0.7022 - 0.1147i
  -0.2045 + 0.2342i   0.7745 - 0.3047i  -0.4586 - 0.0179i
  -0.6860 + 0.0000i  -0.4962 + 0.0000i  -0.5321 + 0.0000i


D =

   -3.1651         0         0
         0    2.8531         0
         0         0    6.3120
```

and

```
S=y*A*y

S =

   8.0000 + 0.0000i   4.0000 + 2.0000i  24.0000 + 0.0000i
   4.0000 - 2.0000i   3.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 3.0000i
  24.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 3.0000i   9.0000 + 0.0000i
```

eigenvalue decomposition of  $S$

```
[U1 D1]=eig(S)

U1 =

   0.6992 - 0.0176i   0.1079 + 0.1024i   0.6989 + 0.0118i
  -0.1411 + 0.1789i   0.8189 - 0.5175i   0.0946 + 0.0260i
  -0.6774 + 0.0000i  -0.1986 + 0.0000i   0.7083 + 0.0000i


D1 =

  -16.5679         0         0
         0    3.7771         0
         0         0   32.7908
```

maybe i am wrong but there should  not be any special relation between eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Comment: it is not proof,just one example from there you may find some relationship

Comment: Yes, I know, It only shows there's no relationship between the two numerically.

I'm still looking forward to a proof if possible.

Comment: better to post on mathoverflow.net

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Thank you for your hint, dato!

Comment: you are welcome my friend